# video should not be downloadable in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, video-streaming, html5-video

I am working on a system where users will be allowed to see the video (like Netflix) but it shouldn't allow them to download it. i have seen my articles but can't get proper help.

If anyone can help, it will be appriciated.

Comment: At Stack Overflow we work on the policy that the user must show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Comment: Is simple, if you send it to the user, he can rip it. You can make this as hard as possible, but there is no "out of the box" solution. This depends alot how you/the user interact with the video. If a simple "GET" request is engough to view the video, you allready lost the game

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hide the content when the user accesses the content via the browser. But you can also filter out some users, complicating the situation. For example, the user opens the video player. You can send a portion of the video stream every X seconds. Your audience will be less likely to struggle to download a fragmented video. Also adding some custom encoding to stream can drop the count. As i said at first, it is impossible to hide client side.

Comment: Remember, they also can use a video capture program while video is playing.